# PHPLOT does not display graph

Tags: php

I would like help if possible with PHPLOT. The chart appears normally with dummy data but when I call the $words array, the chart is not displayed.

chart code:

```
<?php 
include_once ("class/ProcessaPdf.class.php");
require_once 'lib/phplot-5.5.0/phplot.php';

//$words = ProcessaPdf::geraArrayPalavrasChave();

$plot = new PHPlot(640 , 480);

$data = array(
    array('1940' , 6.2 ), 
    array('1950' , 6.2 ),
    array('1960' , 6.3 ),
    array('1970' , 5.8 ),
    );

$plot->SetTitle('Grafico da analise de palavras-chave encontradas');
$plot->SetPlotType("bars");

$plot->SetXLabel("Palavras");
$plot->SetYLabel("Frequencia");

$plot->SetXLabelFontSize(2);
$plot->SetAxisFontSize(2);

$plot->SetDataValues($data);
$plot->SetYDataLabelPos('plotin');

$plot->DrawGraph();

?>
```

if I uncomment the line `//$words = ProcessaPdf::geraArrayPalavrasChave();`
the chart fails

and so I can't replace $data with $word

function that returns $words:

```
static function geraArrayPalavrasChave(){
    $p_chaves = file("./lib/palavras_chave.txt", FILE_TEXT | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    // Initialize and load PDF Parser library 
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser(); 
    
    // Source PDF file to extract text 
    $file = 'lib/projeto.pdf'; 
    
    // Parse pdf file using Parser library 
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($file); 
    
    // Extract text from PDF 
    $text = $pdf->getText();

    for($i=0; $i<count($p_chaves); $i++){
        if(substr_count(' '.$text.' ', ' '.$p_chaves[$i].' ') != ''){
            $dados[$i][] = $p_chaves[$i];
            $dados[$i][] = substr_count(mb_strtoupper(' '.$text.' '), mb_strtoupper(' '.$p_chaves[$i].' '));
        }
    }

   for($i=0; $i<count($dados); $i++){
        $key[] = $i;
    }

    $arrayPalavras = array_combine($key, $dados);

    return $arrayPalavras;

}
```

I tried to generate the graph from the $words array

UPDATE

`$words = ProcessaPdf::geraArrayPalavrasChave();`

returns the the array:

```
Array (     
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => inovações             
        [1] => 3         
    )      
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => tecnologia da informação             
        [1] => 2         
    )      
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => intelectuais             
        [1] => 4         
    )      
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => patente             
        [1] => 5         
    )  
)
```

Comment: The chart fails? Do you mean the code crashes? Or just that you see no Chart?

Comment: Did you try running `geraArrayPalavrasChave()` on its own to see what it does and what it returns

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: just i see no chart. broken image icon appears in html.

Comment: the line $words = ProcessaPdf::geraArrayPalavrasChave(); return the the array:
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => inovações
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => tecnologia da informação
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => intelectuais
            [1] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => patente
            [1] => 5
        )

)`

Comment: _"if I uncomment the line `//$words = ProcessaPdf::geraArrayPalavrasChave();` the chart fails"_ - but you are not even _using_ $words in the rest of that script yet. So that means, it rather can't be because this would have the wrong structure or contains wrong data - but there must be some other actual _error_ triggered by this. What do you see, when you let this line execute - and comment out the final `$plot->DrawGraph();` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I updated the pdfparser library in composer and then updated the autload.
The problem was not in phplot but in pdfparser.